# Improve Postgresql queries selecting latest entries in groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I have recorded events from multiple "users" into a single table, over years. Each user has a `uid`, a timestamp (`when`) and some other individual properties (e.g. version and language), basically like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.events (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass),
    "when" timestamp without time zone,
    uid character(22) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lang character(5) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    osv integer,
    daysrun integer,
)
```

The table has now about 3 million rows, and about 100k unique `uid` values in it.

In many cases, I want to query the properties of the **latest** record for each user (`uid`), i.e. the one with the highest `when` value. This often takes seconds or even minutes, and I wonder if there are ways to speed this up, in postgresql.

Here's an example of my attempt at querying the longest daysrun value for each user:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM events a 
WHERE a.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.uid) c.id 
                FROM events c 
                WHERE c.uid IN ( SELECT DISTINCT m.uid 
                                 FROM events m 
                                 WHERE m.daysrun > 500 ) 
                ORDER BY c.uid, c.daysrun DESC ) 
ORDER BY a.daysrun DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This takes 11s (on a shared web server, single cpu). If I remove the `WHERE` clause, it can take minutes, and can bring the server to its knees.

The above example does not even use `when` for sorting because the `daysrun` value is equivalent in this case. The nesting is done with the following reasoning:

1. (inner) Get every unique `uid`.
2. (middle) Get every row (their id) that has the highest `daysrun` value for each `uid` (here, I could as well have used `when` in place of `daysrun`). *(Though, I am not even sure that this will always give me the highest one)*
3. (outer) Sort the results by `daysrun`.

So, what can be improved about this? Is my query wrong, or can I add better indexes, or other ways, maybe a View that makes this more efficient?

In short, how do I select the rows with the highest `when` value for each `uid`, so that I can then use those twos for further queries?

Comment: Why doesn't have this table a Primary Key? And the `uid character(22)` looks like a FK, and should probably be an integer field.

Comment: The outer `SELECT ... WHERE a.id IN (..)` seems pretty useless. The inner select with the `distinct on()` will already give you that, if you use `distinct on (c.uid) *` instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you - I've now removed the outer query, but I now see why I had added it: Without it, I can't get it ordered by `daysrun`. But that added query makes no difference in performance, anyway. Most of the time is lost in the deeper query, I guess.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is useless. You could also try an `exists` condition rather than an `IN` condition.

Comment: `I want to query the properties of the latest record for each user (uid).` Which implies that `{uid,"when"}` is a *natural key* for the table.

Comment: @wildplasser Can you please explain what you imply by that? I am not experienced with SQL as I write above. Do you mean I should create an index combining `uid` and `when`? How would I use that in an improved query, then?

Comment: What I mean: your table structure is incorrect. (No PK, no UNIQUE set of fields, no FKs defined with supporting indexes, bulky keyfield uid, "lang" is probably a low-cardinality field, dependent on uid, etc) So the query itself is not the cause; the table structure is.

Comment: @wildplasser You mean to turn uid+when into a PK. I could probably do that, though I also already have `id` as a PK. I have recorded these values for years, so I cannot restructure the table, but only add indexes if that might help.

Comment: No, you don't have `id` as a PK (at least not in the DDL you showed us)

Comment: Why would you remove the WHERE clause (presumable the inner most one)?  What is the point of your chain of subselects, if not to implement that WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of inner selects, now you have 3 queries one inside another. You also sort the inner table just to throw it out. You can use aggregate functions to achieve the same result, for example `last_value`:

```
select last_value(col1) over (partition by e.uid order by e.daysrun)
from events e
where e.daysrun > 500
```

I'm using some column `col1`. If performance is important, it's better to fetch only needed data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the partition keyword and last_value() - they are new to me (sqlite is all I know). I'll look into it.

Comment: Okay, this doubles the speed. However, I now get duplicate rows, as they're not grouped by uid. If I have 10 rows with the same uid, I get 10 rows with the same highest daysrun value. That's now what I wanted. I need one row per uid, for the uid with the latest "when" value (or highest daysrun, which is effectively the same row, usually)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann then you can simply group by uid

Comment: Where would I place the "group by e.uid", though? Any place I try results in an error (such as: column "e.daysrun" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann I would have to see the query. But no matter how it looks like if you wrap it in an outer query with `group by` or even `distinct on`, it should work

Comment: The problem is that I want access to the rows (their id) that meet the "latest uid" criteria. I understand now how "partition by" works, but for picking the correct row id in each partition, I cannot use last_value, it seems: If I use your example, with `e.uid` for "col1", I get lots of duplicate uids (and I could then use DISTINCT on them). But if I use `e.id` for "col1", I get many different ids, and DISTINCT won't help then.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann you can probably use `last_value` again. Can you create a db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242828/discussion-between-thomas-tempelmann-and-andronicus).

Answer (score 1):

One option here, which might be feasible depending on how up to date your data must be in the queries, and how often you run this logic, is to create a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rules-materializedviews.html) that contains just the most recent record per uid, and to periodically refresh that.

You run the queries against that instead of the table.

Comment: That's probably the most efficient solution. Never heard of those persistent views before. They're ideal for this purpose.

Comment: No, on the contrary. It is a terrible solution, IMHO. First get your data modelling correct. When that fails you could try rocket science. But first learn how to keep your kite in the air.

Comment: It's a good solution in some circumstances, and in some circumstances – for example when you need a stable result set over a period of time between refreshes despite underlying data changes – it's better than running against the live data.

Comment: Could be. But, IMHO the OP should *first* fix his data model. Currently it looks like a spreadsheet with some indexes added.

Comment: Maybe so, but not everyone who runs a query against a database is in control of their data model, so alternatives are always good. There may be other dependencies that are difficult to alter, also.

Comment: Admittedly, the data is practically just a log file put into a table. How could I improve the data model? Even if I move the uids to a separate table and then ref them from the other one, I still end up with the same problems I'd think. It's just replacing a string with an index into a string table.

Comment: It would be quite easy to test the benefit of an MV here, by creating a table using the appropriate query, and then see how that works for you.

Comment: I've added a fiddle that demonstrates the issue of getting the ids: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b57da9a03cd8a8a2db6696faf3ca302a - you'll see that I do not get the latest ID for all same uids as expected, so I can't determine the IDs of the latest row in each uid group.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery can be used directly as a table, not just as the input of a IN list.  Using it as a table is what you want to do here to allow you to sort one way before the DISTINCT ON and another way after it.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.uid) * 
                FROM events c  
                ORDER BY c.uid, c.daysrun DESC ) a
ORDER BY a.daysrun DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Assigning an alias to the subquery is syntactically required, but the alias doesn't need to be used as only one set of columns is in scope at any one time.  I find this easier to read and understand:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (uid) * 
                FROM events  
                ORDER BY uid, daysrun DESC ) a
ORDER BY daysrun DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, then you at least need to include an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of it.

Comment: That's still leading to a very slow query (24s). If I limit the inner query with "where daysrun > 1000", it's much faster. "EXPLAIN" tells me that while the faster one uses quicksort (Memory: 366kB), the unrestricted query says: "Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 332632kB", "Buffers: shared hit=14862 read=38699, temp read=110786 written=110786". So the problem is clearly with the number of rows and needing a two-level sort, and I am looking for ways to improve that process. Merge sort is clearly inferior over qs. Probably a memory space issue.

Comment: Including `WHERE m.daysrun > 500` is grotty, but effective, as long as you have some way to guess what value to use for 500.  Maybe you should just do that.  There is a very efficient way to do this that is cleaner than guessing such a threshold, but there is no way I know of to hook that algorithm up to a traditional SQL statement.  You could do it with plpython or plperl but that itself would be grotty.